# django. view. параметры

Tags: python, django

Есть страница с кучей полей (пусть это будут обычные input)

[...]

```
input name="names[0]" value="1"
input name="names[1]" value="2"
input name="names[2]" value="3"
```

[...]

Подскажите, каким образом их можно передать во view списком, а не отдельными полями?
Т.е. получить что-то вроде этого

```
def process_names(request, names):
    # names - список
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ можно увидеть здесь:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528663/django-form-pass-parameter-from-template-to-view-by-submit-button

т.е. в странице должно быть:

```
input name="test" value="1"
input name="test" value="2"
input name="test" value="3"
```

а во вьюхе тогда можно сделать так:

```
def process_names(request):
    # POST или GET, зависит от того, каким методом посылаются данные во вьюху
    test = request.POST.getlist('test') # test = [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

как правильно заметили, надо чтобы name был одинаковый. и getlist получаешь список. 
данные передаются с помощью формы через POST-запрос.
Заключаешь свои в <form action="урл твоей вьюхи"></form>

дальше пишешь в таком духе

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if 'mmo' in request.POST:
        s_mmo = int(request.POST['mmo'])
```

для файлов

```
    if request.FILES:
        if 'photo' in request.FILES: 
            photolist = request.FILES.getlist('photo')
            SavePhotos(photolist,flat)
```

либо же передавай AJAX'ом, через GET-параметры . Обработка такая же как и для POST,только POST на GET меняешь